# Error: QueryInterface' : function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: com

GFXComShapeObjectsLib::IAIFileReaderPtr spAIFileReader;

m_pObj->QueryInterface(&spAIFileReader);

error C2660: 'CAIFileReader::QueryInterface' : function does not take 1 arguments

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The QueryInterface should have 2 arguments, one is the Identifier of the querying interface, one is the Address of pointer variable that receives the interface pointer requested. You can refer MSDN online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx